# looping in vue js like in php foreach to get html table

Tags: javascript, php, foreach, vue.js, v-for

I have array of objects like this

```
types:[
    { name:"Twin/Double", rooms:[{id:4}, {id:5}] },
    { name:"Twin/Double", rooms:[{id:2}, {id:3}] },
    { name:"Twin/Double", rooms:[{id:6}, {id:7}] },
];
```

So I want to loop over them in vue.js  like in php foreach loop in table and get result like this.

PHP loop.

```
<table v-for="type in rooms">
   <tbody>
      @foreach($types as $type)
        <tr>
           <td>{{ type->name }}</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach($type->rooms as $room)
             <tr>{{ $room->id }}
        @endforeach
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But in vue.js v-for directive I cant do the same I try to something like this.

Vue loop.

```
<tbody>
   <div v-for="type in rooms">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ type.name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="room in type.rooms">{{ room.id }}</tr>
   </div>
</tbody>
```

But my table structure has broked. I want to get structure exactly like this.

HTML Table result

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Twin/Double</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Room - 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Room - 5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Triple</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>Room - 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Room - 3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Family</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Room - 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Room - 7</td>
    </tr>
```

visual result must be like this.[image]

Please help me

Comment: you don't have table headers in your example and no closing tag for tbody either. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @samayo I only want with this example with closed tbody. I have thad with th-s.

Comment: maybe add a simple table of what the output is supposed to look like then

Comment: @samayo I added image of final result you can watch it.

Comment: can you check the answer? let me know if it works for you

Comment: well, like I said I don't get it. Maybe someone who does will help, but your example (html) output is not the same as the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems Vamsi has technically given the solution, but the markup needed to also be fixed with an extra `<td></td>` around the room ID.

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tbody>
     <template v-for="type in types">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ type.name }}</td>
        </tr>
       <tr v-for="room in type.rooms">
         <td>Room - {{ room.id }}</td>
       </tr>
     </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        types:[
          { name:"Twin/Double", rooms:[{id:4}, {id:5}] },
          { name:"Triple", rooms:[{id:2}, {id:3}] },
          { name:"Family", rooms:[{id:6}, {id:7}] },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  tr, td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1.314em;
  }
</style>
```

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) tag instead of `<div>` for looping so that the table structure is not broken:

```
<tbody>
   <template v-for="type in rooms">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ type.name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="room in type.rooms">{{ room.id }}</tr>
   </template>
</tbody>
```

The `<template>` tag will not be rendered but its children's will be rendered . You can think the `<template>` tag as a placeholder